# Cannot parse time

Tags: here-api

I've tried to use access hours in FindSequence request^
destination1=FrankfurtAirport;50.050639,8.569641;acc:mo07:30:00+00:00|mo11:00:00Z;st:600

It's simial docs. And I've got an error:
"Cannot parse time: mo07:30:00 00:00. Hours must be in the range [0,23], minutes and seconds in the range [0,59]. Error ID: aa307f79-b9ae-489d-b0a9-52f8607b2ca1"

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The waypoint id can be followed by a semicolon separated list of constraints. Supported constraints:
before, acc,at,st

The value consists of two timestamps with day, time and time zone information in the format:

**acc:DDhh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]|DDhh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]**

For access hours days (DD) are abbreviated with two lowercase characters: **mo** for Monday, **tu** for Tuesday, **we, th, fr, sa, su**. Hours (hh) must integer values in the range 0..23. Minutes and seconds must be from the range 0..59. The first time stamp defines the beginning of the access hours, the second time stamp defines the end of the access hours.

The format is as xsd type xs:datetime. The access hours constraints require a service time, which is the length time (to be spent) at the waypoint.

To specify a time zone, you can either enter a date in UTC time by adding a "Z" behind the date, or an offset from the UTC time by adding a positive or negative time behind the date

for example:
**2019-09-24Z or 2019-09-24-06:00 or 2019-09-24+06:00 // acc:mo09:30:00-01:00|12:00:00-01:00;st:600**

Supporting with illustration covering both formats :

https://wse.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json?departure=2019-05-04T8:00:00-01:00&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&app_id=XXXXXXXX&app_code=YYYYYYYY&start=DuisburgRuhrort;51.4541,6.7406&destination1=ZecheZollverein;51.486,7.0459;acc:mo09:30:00-02:00|mo12:00:00-02:00;st:600&destination2=KokereiZollverein;51.4879,7.0337;acc:mo07:30:00Z|mo11:00:00Z;st:600&destination3=MuehlheimRuhrHbf;51.432,6.886;acc:mo07:30:00Z|mo11:00:00Z;st:600&end=DuisburgHafen;51.4576,6.7717&improveFor=TIME

For more details,refer : developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/topics/api-reference-findsequence.html